# Show that the function $f$ is well-defined and continuous.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, continuity, retraction

Let $U_{i}$ be a bounded path component of $X = \mathbb{R}^2 \setminus J,$ and assume $\partial U_{i} \neq J.$ Choose a point $c \in U_{i}.$ Use the retraction $r,$ we define the function $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2 - \{c\} $ by the rule $$ f(\mathbf{x}) = \begin{cases} 
      r(\mathbf{x}) & \text{if } x \in \overline{U_{i}} \\
      \mathbf{x} &  \text{if } x \in \mathbb{R}^2 \setminus U_{i}
   \end{cases} $$

Show that the function $f$ is well-defined and continuous.

**My previous knowledge is:**

I know that $\partial U_{i}$ is either all of $J$(where $J$ is a Jordan curve) or it is contained in an arc $A \subseteq J.$

And this question explains some prior knowledge:

[Show that $\partial U_{i}$ is either all of $J$ or it is contained in an arc $A \subseteq J.$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3649259/show-that-partial-u-i-is-either-all-of-j-or-it-is-contained-in-an-arc-a)

**My questions are:**

1-Should not the $\mathbf{x}$ and the $x$ in the question be the same?

2- I know that the retraction is a continuous function by definition and I know that the identity function is also a continuous function. Does this implies that our $f$ is continuous? But it is a piecewise function. Could anyone help me with the proof of continuity please?

3-I know that to show that a function is well-defined you have to start with $x=y$ and ends up with  $f(x) = f(y)$.... I am not sure how to implement this in our case. Could anyone help me with this proof also?

**EDIT:**

I was given this hint for the solution of this problem : $\overline{U_{i}}$ and $X \setminus U_{i}$ are both closed in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Comment: What is $r$ exactly? It is a retraction of what to what? $f$ being well defined means that both pieces have the same value on the intersection. Meaning $r(x)=x$ when $x\in\overline{U_i}\cap(\mathbb{R}^2\backslash U_i)$. But this would mean that $r$ is a retraction from $\overline{U_i}$ to $\partial U_i$? Such retraction cannot exist, just like $S^1$ is not a retract of $D^2$ (note that by the Jordan curve theorem $\overline{U_i}$ is homeomorphic to $D^2$ and $\partial U_i$ to $S^1$).

Comment: okay just give me 10 minuit to think @freakish

Comment: @freakish I edited my question with this hint: "I was given this hint for the solution of this problem : $\overline{U_{i}}$ and $X \setminus U_{i}$ are both closed in $\mathbb{R}^2$"

Comment: Is this really the meaning of $f$ well defined? @freakish

Comment: @freakish is $f$ a continuous function?

Comment: I think your statement of Jordan Curve theorem is different from what I am going to prove .... am I correct?@freakish

Comment: You didn't answer my question: what is $r$ exactly?

Comment: @Smart20 - freakish did not give a statement of the Jordan curve theorem. They gave a result that follows from it. Why? Because you didn't state that you were trying to prove the Jordan curve theorem by contradiction, so freakish was not aware of this. This is only one of many glaring omissions of context in your question. Please remember that we are not espers nor have we been looking over your shoulder as you worked on this. The only things we know are what you tell us.

Comment: @PaulSinclair the problem is that my questions are related to each other and I am unwise in choosing which to write and which to not write .... sorry about that.

Comment: @freakish Oh I see it is a retraction from $\mathbb{R}^2 \to A$  where $A$ is any arc in $X$ .... we proved that "In a normal space $X$ every arc $A$ in $X$ is a retract of $X$ " .... sorry about that.

Comment: @freakish I think this function will be well defined if $S^1$ is a retract of $D^2.$ which is not our case .... am I correct? .... yes I am trying to prove the Jordan curve theorem by contradiction

Comment: @Smart20 maybe you're right. It's hard for me to judge, there's not enough details.

Comment: What other details you require to help me in the solution of this problem?@freakish

Comment: Also, How will the given hint help me in the solution?@freakish

Comment: I am also going to post a question (within 10 minuets) that I want to solve depending on this function? I hope you can look at it may reveal some of the details you want ..... I have a lot of hard problems that really stuck me in my route towards the proof.

Comment: Also, all my previous questions are related to each other @freakish .... and I have added what is exactly $r$ is.

Comment: Here is the question that may reveal what I want to prove here @freakish https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3650300/use-the-function-f-to-show-that-s1-is-a-retract-of-mathbbr2

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, $\mathbf x$ and $x$ are the same. All we see is what you typeset, but if your source typeset them the same way, they differ only because someone goofed.
2. No, being pieced together from two continuous pieces does not by itself prove that $f$ is continuous. $$h(t) = \begin{cases}1 & t \le 0\\0 & t > 0\end{cases}$$ is pieced together from continuous pieces, but is not continuous. You need to address continuity separately on the interiors of the pieces (where it does follow from continuity of the piece functions) and on the boundary, where you need to show that the limit converges to the function value, no matter from which side the boundary point is approached.
3. "Well-defined" means that for each point $x$ in the domain, $f(x)$ has one and only one value assigned to it by the definition. You have definitions on $\overline{U_i}$ and on $\Bbb R^2 \setminus U_i$. What you need to show is that for each point in $\overline{U_i} \cap (\Bbb R^2 \setminus U_i)$, these two definitions agree.

Note that you need to show "well-defined" before you examine continuity, since you can hardly show that the limit as you approach the boundary is the function value at the boundary before you have established there is a function value at the boundary. (Besides which, in this case, knowing that the two pieces agree on the boundary is critical to proving continuity there.)

Comment: My source typed them differently.

Comment: So you are saying that this function has a problem in being well defined for the same reason @freakish mentioned .... am I correct?

Comment: No. I am telling what you need to do to show it is well-defined. @freakish is pointing out that you introduce $r$ without bothering to explain to us what it is, and is asking you to explain it (in vain, because you keep ignoring this request). While freakish is trying to understand your proof, I simply went forward with the assumption that $r$ is just sume function defined on $\overline U_i$. How it fits into your overall proof, I cannot say, because, just like freakish, I don't know what it is or what properties it has.

Comment: I am still thinking about it as the original statement did not say $r$ is a retraction of what.

Comment: You need to search your textbook to find it. It is obviously referencing something done just a little earlier that discussed such a retraction.

Comment: Oh I see it is a retraction from $\mathbb{R}^2 \to A$  where $A$ is any arc in $X$ .... we proved that "In a normal space $X$ every arc $A$ in $X$ is a retract of $X$ " .... sorry about that.

Comment: @freakish I think this function will be well defined if $S^1$ is a retract of $D^2.$ which is not our case .... am I correct?

Comment: But what is the importance of the hint given for the solution?